# How to use system() in R?

Tags: r

I want to invoke a system command to change directory in R console.

For example,

```
system(paste('"cd C:/Users/Dropbox/RPackages"'),intern = TRUE)
system(paste('"R CMD build test"'))
system(paste('"R CMD check test"'))
system(paste('"R CMD INSTALL test"'))
library(test)
```

These commands are supposed to run in Windows Command Prompt. But I want to bury them inside the RGUI script file to allow the change of parameters by users before wrap it into a Package.The error message I got from R console is

```
Error in system(paste("\"cd C:/Users/Dropbox/RPackages"\""), intern = TRUE) : 
'"cd C:/Users/Dropbox/RPackages"' not found
```

I also tried

```
system("cd C:/Users/Dropbox/RPackages",intern = TRUE)
```

but got similar error message

```
Error in system("cd C:/Users/Dropbox/RPackages", intern = TRUE) : 
'cd' not found
```

Comment: isnt this what `devtools` is designed to do? https://github.com/hadley/devtools

Comment: As @Chase mentioned, rather than doing all this yourself, you might want to use `devtools::check`.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you use the R command `setwd()` to change directories -- see `help(setwd)` -- instead?

Answer (score 2):

`system()` runs each command in its own interpreter. Any change made to the working directory will not propagate.

If you want to do several things in a working directory, put all the commands in one `system` call, separated by a semi-colon (this works for Linux shells, not sure about Windows). Separating with \n also works in Linux, try that?

Compare these:

```
> getwd()
[1] "/nobackup/rowlings/Downloads/Dirs"
> system("cd Foo; pwd")
/nobackup/rowlings/Downloads/Dirs/Foo
> system("cd Foo") ; system(" pwd")
/nobackup/rowlings/Downloads/Dirs
```

Depending on your actual problem you might be better off using `setwd()` in R.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried double back slashes?

```
'C:\\Users\\Dropbox\\RPackages'
```

Had a similar issue with R in Windows 7 using:

```
download.file(url=<url>, destfile='C:\\<dir>\\<dir>\\<file>')
```